# Issue hiding navigation bar border line | Swift

Tags: swift

Essentially I have the following in my app delegate:

```
let myColor = UIColor.white
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let barAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    let toolbarAppearance = UIToolbarAppearance()
    barAppearance.backgroundColor = myColor
    toolbarAppearance.backgroundColor = myColor
    
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBar.standardAppearance = barAppearance
    navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = barAppearance
    
    let toolBar = UIToolbar.appearance()
    toolBar.standardAppearance = toolbarAppearance
    
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        toolBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = toolbarAppearance
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

To hide the borders one at the bottom on the navigation bar I tried doing the following, but nothing happens:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: What's the question? You seem to have just forgotten the shadow removal code in your app delegate.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I don't want the border removal code to be present on all view controllers across the app just the specific one I am working with - using the shadow, UIImage code above fails to remove the bar. why is this not working on the specific view controller?

Comment: You have to do it the same way you did it before, by way of UINavigationBarAppearance. You can use appearanceWhenContainedIn to specify a particular nav bar.